# iOS 17.2 Journal app?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

This morning I updated my iPhone and iPad to iOS 17.2. They both now say I am up-to date with iOS 17.2, However, only my phone has the new Journal app. It wasn’t included on my iPad 8, not even in the App Search. Anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Journal app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/journal/id6447391597) is iPhone only at launch (17.2) just like the [classical music app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-music-classical/id1598433714), weather, and the health app were iPhone only for quite some time. Each later down the line arrived on the iPad with enhanced layouts for the larger viewport.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-started-with-journal-iph0e5ca7dd3/ios

I haven't seen Apple commit to making it an iPad / Mac app, but it makes sense if people like the app and use it, it might grow to iPadOS, too.

The journal app is slightly different than the classical music app since it's considering very personal and private data like health app.

Comment: Apple Music Classical is a media consumption app which is well-suited for a phone. Journal fundamentally involves writing text, which is best done on the iPad and Mac, so the differences support it being on iPad and Mac.

Comment: I agree @user71659 with the benefit of a larger screen for journaling. I expect I’ll use a keyboard with my iPhone if I end up using journaling app - just like I carry a keyboard for serious work on iPhone in other text editors. The iPad version of classical music is excellent for discovery, so it’s also beneficial to me to have it on the iPad.